# How to force Microsoft Database Project generate ALTER statement for primary key constraint instead of creating temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have following script for LoginLogo table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [LoginLogo] (
    [LoginLogoId]           INT               IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginId]               INT               NOT NULL,
    [LogoNm]                NVARCHAR(255)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LoginLogo_LoginLogoId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoginId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LoginLogo_LoginId] FOREIGN KEY ([LoginId]) 
    REFERENCES [Login] ([LoginId])
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IF_LoginLogo_LoginId]
    ON [LoginLogo]([LoginId] ASC)
    ON [INDX];
```

I need to change Primary Key Constraint, so I've just changed one line, please see below the change:

```sql
CONSTRAINT [PK_LoginLogo_LoginLogoId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoginLogoId] ASC),
```

Database project perfectly build changed code, but when it generates database update statement it generates temp table instead of simple ALTER statement. See below generated script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [tmp_ms_xx_LoginLogo] (
    [LoginLogoId]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginId]            INT            NOT NULL,
    [LogoNm]             NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [tmp_ms_xx_constraint_PK_LoginLogo_LoginLogoId1] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoginLogoId] ASC)
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
           FROM   [apps].[LoginLogo])
    BEGIN
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [apps].[tmp_ms_xx_LoginLogo] ON;
        INSERT INTO [apps].[tmp_ms_xx_LoginLogo] ([LoginLogoId], [LoginId], [LogoNm])
        SELECT   [LoginLogoId],
                 [LoginId],
                 [LogoNm],
        FROM     [LoginLogo]
        ORDER BY [LoginLogoId] ASC;
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [tmp_ms_xx_LoginLogo] OFF;
    END

DROP TABLE [LoginLogo];

EXECUTE sp_rename N'[tmp_ms_xx_LoginLogo]', N'LoginLogo';

EXECUTE sp_rename N'[tmp_ms_xx_constraint_PK_LoginLogo_LoginLogoId1]',
N'PK_LoginLogo_LoginLogoId', N'OBJECT';
```

Is it possible to tell Database project to generate ALTER statement instead of creating temp table? How can I force Microsoft Database Project to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Bearing in mind that if you change the clustered index of a table, the table will be rebuilt *regardless* of whether the script does `ALTER TABLE` or the SSDT-generated stuff with temp tables, the usual way to solve these problems is to do the `ALTER` ahead of time

Meaning, you need a script, often referred to as a pre-pre-deploy script (pre-deploy won't work, as it is run post-comparison) that makes the expensive change, so that when the comparison is run the change has already occurred, and hence doesn't get repeated by the dacpac deployment.

This script needs to be run as part of your deployment, before you do any of the `sqlpackage` stuff. You can specify the change as `alter table` in this script.

In this particular instance, where the table is going to be rebuilt either way, I can't see it making a great deal of difference to the overall deployment time.